# pdo select with a php variable

Tags: php, pdo, php-5.3

Ok so i have a table with username,poke1hp,poke2hp all the way up to poke6hp
I have made it so i store the table e.g poke1hp  in side a php variable the problem is now i want to select from the column from what ever is in the variable and get what ever is in side that column. 
So he is what i have done so far.

This stores the table name in side the $tablename

```
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '1') {$tablename = "poke1hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '2') {$tablename = "poke2hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '3') {$tablename = "poke3hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '4') {$tablename = "poke4hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '5') {$tablename = "poke5hp";}
if ($_SESSION['pickedslot'] == '6') {$tablename = "poke6hp";}
```

I then do a pdo select to see if i can grab what is in side the column

```
$grabhpbaby = $db->prepare("select '$tablename' from new_battles WHERE username = ?");
$grabhpbaby->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$grabhpbaby2 = $grabhpbaby->fetch(); 

echo $grabhpbaby2[$tablename];
```

for some reason the select is echoing out the column name which is in side $tablename  and not what is in the column.   I am trying to make a battle script and i am storing the users hp/life in the db and i am storing pick monster they have chosen in side the session variable pickedslot. So if the user is on monster one then the monster 1s life/hp will be stored in side the column poke1hp so im trying to echo out the hp of what ever is in side the column of the monster there on..  Has i have said the if staments work fine and the column name is stored in the $tablename but for some resson the select is echoing out the column name and not what's in side the column

I have tried changing the echo to

```
echo $grabhpbaby2[$tablename];

echo $grabhpbaby2["$tablename"];
```

but still only get the column name and not what's in side the column

Comment: Your database setup is an awful one

Comment: well how would you set it up then ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because your passing the fieldname as a literal value to the query.

```
$grabhpbaby = $db->prepare("select '$tablename' from new_battles WHERE username = ?");
```

you have to change it and remove the quotes around it

```
$grabhpbaby = $db->prepare("select $tablename from new_battles WHERE username = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
$grabhpbaby = $db->prepare("select '$tablename' from new_battles WHERE username = ?");
```

to the following

```
$grabhpbaby = $db->prepare("select $tablename from new_battles WHERE username = ?");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to properly set the placeholder column in your prepare query:

```
$grabhpbaby = $db->prepare('select ' . $tablename . ' from new_battles WHERE username = ?');
$grabhpbaby->execute(array($_SESSION['username']));
$grabhpbaby2 = $grabhpbaby->fetchColumn(); 

echo $grabhpbaby2;
```